# importing command arguments from another class

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I have to been working on a plugin for a couple of days or so now and I'm not sure on how to do this. I have a command /punish  which opens an inventory where moderators can mute, kick, ban or warn the player in arg[0]. once the command has opened the first inventory, I made a different class called guievents which controls the inventory. My question is, how do I get the args from the command in one class to another class. I've been searching on google for a while and most of the time I found people using hashmaps, however, I never quite understood how they were doing it, or if I should use hashmaps at all.
Command Class:

```
package io.github.bxnie.gui.punish;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemFlag;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;

import net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.CommandExecute;

public class punish extends CommandExecute implements Listener, CommandExecutor{

    public String punish = "punish";

    //open main GUI for moderation /punish
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        Player p = (Player) sender;
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage("Only players may execute this command!");
            return true;
        }
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(punish) && sender instanceof Player) {
            if (p.hasPermission("fp.punish")) {
                if (args.length == 0){
                    p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + ChatColor.BOLD + "Fiore" + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "] " + ChatColor.RED + "Correct usage: " + ChatColor.GRAY + ChatColor.ITALIC + "/punish <player>");
                    return false;
                }
                if (args.length >= 1){
                    String message = "";
                    Player target = Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0]);
                    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                        message = message + args[i] + " ";
                    }
                    if (message.length() == 0){
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + ChatColor.BOLD + "Fiore" + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "] " + ChatColor.RED + "Correct usage: " + ChatColor.GRAY + ChatColor.ITALIC + "/punish <player>");
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (target == null){
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "[" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + ChatColor.BOLD + "Fiore" + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "] " + ChatColor.RED + "Correct usage: " + ChatColor.GRAY + ChatColor.ITALIC + "player not online");
                        return false;
                    }
                    //Creates the Inventory
                    Inventory punishgui = Bukkit.createInventory(null, 9, ChatColor.RED + "Punish Menu");

                    //Where the Items and Meta are made
                    ItemStack warn = new ItemStack(Material.CONCRETE, 1, (short) 14);
                    ItemMeta warnmeta = warn.getItemMeta();
                    warnmeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.RED + "Warn Player");
                    warnmeta.addItemFlags(ItemFlag.HIDE_ATTRIBUTES);
                    ArrayList<String> warnlore = new ArrayList<String>();
                    warnlore.add(ChatColor.GRAY + "Click this to Warn the Selected Player!");
                    warnmeta.setLore(warnlore);
                    warn.setItemMeta(warnmeta);

                    ItemStack kick = new ItemStack(Material.CONCRETE, 1);
                    ItemMeta kickmeta = kick.getItemMeta();
                    kickmeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.WHITE + "Kick Player");
                    kickmeta.addItemFlags(ItemFlag.HIDE_ATTRIBUTES);
                    ArrayList<String> kicklore = new ArrayList<String>();
                    kicklore.add(ChatColor.GRAY + "Click this to Kick the Selected Player!");
                    kickmeta.setLore(kicklore);
                    kick.setItemMeta(kickmeta);

                    ItemStack mute = new ItemStack(Material.CONCRETE, 1, (short) 1);
                    ItemMeta mutemeta = mute.getItemMeta();
                    mutemeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GOLD + "Mute Player");
                    mutemeta.addItemFlags(ItemFlag.HIDE_ATTRIBUTES);
                    ArrayList<String> mutelore = new ArrayList<String>();
                    mutelore.add(ChatColor.GRAY + "Click this to Mute the Selected Player!");
                    mutemeta.setLore(mutelore);
                    mute.setItemMeta(mutemeta);

                    ItemStack tempban = new ItemStack(Material.CONCRETE, 1, (short) 7);
                    ItemMeta tempbanmeta = tempban.getItemMeta();
                    tempbanmeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GRAY + "TempBan Player");
                    tempbanmeta.addItemFlags(ItemFlag.HIDE_ATTRIBUTES);
                    ArrayList<String> tempbanlore = new ArrayList<String>();
                    tempbanlore.add(ChatColor.GRAY + "Click this to TempBan the Selected Player!");
                    tempbanmeta.setLore(tempbanlore);
                    tempban.setItemMeta(tempbanmeta);

                    ItemStack ban = new ItemStack(Material.CONCRETE, 1, (short) 15);
                    ItemMeta banmeta = ban.getItemMeta();
                    banmeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "Ban Player");
                    banmeta.addItemFlags(ItemFlag.HIDE_ATTRIBUTES);
                    ArrayList<String> banlore = new ArrayList<String>();
                    banlore.add(ChatColor.GRAY + "Click this to Ban the Selected Player!");
                    banmeta.setLore(banlore);
                    ban.setItemMeta(banmeta);

                    //Positioning
                    punishgui.setItem(2, warn);
                    punishgui.setItem(3, kick);
                    punishgui.setItem(4, mute);
                    punishgui.setItem(5, tempban);
                    punishgui.setItem(6, ban);

                    p.openInventory(punishgui);
                }
            } else {
                p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Insufficient Permission!");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

one of the guievents classes:

```
package io.github.bxnie.events.punish;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryClickEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;

import io.github.bxnie.gui.punish.punish;
import io.github.bxnie.gui.punish.punishmain;

public class punishmutemenu implements Listener {

    @EventHandler
    public void InventoryOnClick(InventoryClickEvent event) {
        Player player = (Player) event.getWhoClicked();
        Inventory open = event.getInventory();
        ItemStack item = event.getCurrentItem();

        if(open.getName().equals(ChatColor.RED + "Mute Time Menu")) {
            event.setCancelled(true);
            if(item == null || !item.hasItemMeta()) {
                return;
            }
            if(item.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(ChatColor.BLUE + "< Back")) {
                player.openInventory(punishmain.punishmaingui());
                return;
            }
            if(item.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(ChatColor.BLUE + "5 Minutes")) {
                Bukkit.dispatchCommand(player, "mute " + name + " 5mins");
                return;
            }
            if(item.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(ChatColor.BLUE + "10 Minutes")) {
                Bukkit.dispatchCommand(player, "mute " + name + " 10mins");
                return;
            }
            if(item.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(ChatColor.BLUE + "30 Minutes")) {
                Bukkit.dispatchCommand(player, "mute " + name + " 30mins");
                return;
            }
            if(item.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(ChatColor.BLUE + "1 Hour")) {
                Bukkit.dispatchCommand(player, "mute " + name + " 1hour");
                return;
            }
            if(item.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(ChatColor.BLUE + "3 Hours")) {
                Bukkit.dispatchCommand(player, "mute " + name + " 3hours");
                return;
            }
            if(item.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(ChatColor.BLUE + "24 Hours")) {
                Bukkit.dispatchCommand(player, "mute " + name + " 1day");
                return;
            }
            if(item.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(ChatColor.BLUE + "7 Days")) {
                Bukkit.dispatchCommand(player, "mute " + name + " 7days");
                return;
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

in the second screenshot, I put a temporary "name" as a placeholder as i dont know what to put. if anyone is to reply, could you like explain what you are doing just so i dont fall short of this again.
Thanks

Comment: So, as far as i can see, what you need your inventory class to know, is the player to punish, right? where do u instanciate the menu? simply pass the player to punish in its constructor.

Comment: how would I do that since the player to punish is different depending on what was typed in, /punish <username>, I can fetch the arg[0] from the onCommand, but I'm not sure on how to "export" that and use it in another class. would i use a HashMap? if so how would i go about setting that up

Answer (score 0):

You could use HashMaps,

What you should do is make a HashMap in your CommandClass.

Make the Player object the Key and the arg(s) the value like this: 
HashMap myHashMap - In case of a single argument.

HashMap myHashMap - In case of multiple arguments.

Then each time before you open the GUI you should put the Player and Arg(s) in the HashMap. You should implement methods in your command class for fetching the values, for example, public String getArg(Player player), and return the value. And also a remove method(This will prevent errors) called, public void removeArgs(Player player), this should be called when the GUI is closed or whenever you like it.

Hope you could find any use in this.

Comment: yeah thank you, ill give it a shot, ill comment here what my results were

Comment: just a quick question how do i put the Player and Arg(s) into the hash map, sorry this is my first time really using them

Comment: myHashMap.put(Player, Args);

Comment: and im creating the Hashmap Outside the onCommand Constructor so for example like this 
`public HashMap<Player, args> arghash = new HashMap<Player, args>();`

this is where i get confused, do i put it inside or outside the constructor

Comment: You totally can, as that happens directly when the class gets initiated. But mind if you wanna limit the access of your HashMap by making it private or any other [access modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) and use methods. You should also store the commandClass instance in the Event class in a field, so you won't have to use static methods as that is a bad habit.

Comment: Also you can get the command class instance in your event class by adding a constructor in your event class asking for the Command Class instance, so you first have to initiate your command class so you can pass the instance when you register your event class. And no you do not have to initiate the HashMap in the constructor. I hope my advice helped anyways have a good night

Comment: I have tried to set this up as best I can but I can't seem to get it working every time I try a different method or different strings when the command runs its mutes the player "null" instead of the player I entered

Comment: I am not going to spoonfeed everything but here is an example of how you can do it(Note I only added my methods so existing errors is on your behalf)
CommandClass: https://pastebin.com/QnXqTD2N
EventClass: https://pastebin.com/n5jQWVLf

I'd also like to point out how you do your naming conventions as I've found out you didn't follow them so here is a guide for you: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/

I hope this sums it up for you

Comment: thanks for the help, although it still isn't working, I still mute the player "null" instead of the player I typed in
https://gyazo.com/7f6c24d867b49754d2e3f6fd908d6c35

Comment: so after playing around with some of the lines of code you sent me and testing different things, I managed to get this instead of "null" https://gyazo.com/6b05441442bb672436545ca613d595b4
still pretty far from what I want and I'm not sure if this is better or worse than just a "null" output.

Comment: Can you give me the full source code of your plugins with github etc. So I can view all the errors

Comment: my plugin in like a bunch of things, this is just one of the things inside it but here you go https://github.com/Bxnie/FiorePlugin